# Typesetting a pattern matching equation

Tags: math-mode, equations, amsmath

I want to typeset an equation for a paper.  In the field of computer science we can define an equation that depends upon the form of one of it's arguments.  I want to typeset this with LaTeX & `amsmath`.

I might write it as follows in a program, I'm using a familiar example:

```
fib 0 = 1
fib 1 = 1
fib X = (fib (X - 1)) + (fib (X - 2))
```

This could be typeset to appear as:

```
fib X = { 1                              if X < 2
        { (fib (X - 1)) + (fib (X - 2))  otherwise
```

And I know how to do this using amsmath's align and case environments.  But I'd prefer the pattern match or guards to appear on the left of the equation, the same way they would in the program above.  Can someone point me at how I can do this?

This is what I have so far using \begin{array}{llcl} but the spacing doesn't look right.  This is the actual equation I'm trying to typeset,  fibs is just a familiar example.

```
$$
\begin{array}{llcl}
\operatorname{prodtime}\,V & X = Y &=& 0 \\
\operatorname{prodtime}\,V & X = f(\ldots)                &=& 0 \\
\operatorname{prodtime}\,V & p(X_1,\,\ldots,\,X_n)        &=& 
\operatorname{prodtime}\,V\,(\operatorname{body}\,p) \\
\operatorname{prodtime}\,V & V = \,f(X_1,\,\ldots,\,X_n)  &=&
    \operatorname{prodtime}\,V\,(\operatorname{body}\,f) \\
\operatorname{prodtime}\,V & X_0(X_1,\,\ldots,\,X_n)      &=& time\_of\_call \\
\operatorname{prodtime}\,V & m(X_1,\,\ldots,\,X_n)        &=& time\_of\_call \\
\operatorname{prodtime}\,V & foreign(\ldots)              &=& 0 \\
\operatorname{prodtime}\,V & G_{head},\,G_{tail}
\end{array}
$$
```

Comment: Please upload an image that shows how you want this typeset.

Comment: Please post the code used to produce this -- the spacing is easy to fix, but would be nice to have something to start with.

Comment: So what's wrong with the spacing? Also, you `fib` example condensed the expression into a single subject, while your newer example has `prodtime` at every row/item. What *exactly* are you after?

Comment: I've gone with repeating 'prodtime' for every one of its equations.  I've seen other authors only give the name of the function once.  Anyway, thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without an image of exactly how you want this typeset it is difficult to know for sure, but perhaps one of these is what you are looking for:

[image]

or perhaps:

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\fib}{\mathrm{fib}}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
    &\text{if }  x < 2 & \fib X &= 1 \\
    &\text{otherwise } & \fib X &= (\fib (X - 1)) + (\fib (X - 2))
\end{align*}
Another option is:
\begin{align*}
\fib X = \begin{cases}
    \text{if }  x < 2 & = 1 \\
    \text{otherwise } & = (\fib (X - 1)) + (\fib (X - 2))
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

---

Here is how you can modify the given MWE to obtain better spacing:

[image]

### Notes:

- `@{}` is used to eliminate the inter column spacing
- I added `{}` before the `=` to get proper math spacing.
- I replaced the `$$ ... $$` with `\[ ... \]`. See [Why is \[ ... \] preferable to $$ ... $$?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to) for more details.
- Changes as per egreg's suggestions:

  1. `\mathit{foreign}`, `\mathit{time\_of\_call}` and `\mathrm{head}` for better appearance of the formulas.
  2. Removed `\,` after `\prodtime`, and the other uses of `\operatorname`.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\prodtime}{\operatorname{prodtime}}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{l l @{}l}
\prodtime V & X = Y                        &{}= 0 \\
\prodtime V & X = f(\ldots)                &{}= 0 \\
\prodtime V & p(X_1,\,\ldots,\,X_n)        &{}= \prodtime V\,(\operatorname{body} p) \\
\prodtime V & V = \,f(X_1,\,\ldots,\,X_n)  &{}= \prodtime V\,(\operatorname{body} f) \\
\prodtime V & X_0(X_1,\,\ldots,\,X_n)      &{}= \mathit{time\_of\_call} \\
\prodtime V & m(X_1,\,\ldots,\,X_n)        &{}= \mathit{time\_of\_call} \\
\prodtime V & \mathit{foreign}(\ldots)     &{}= 0 \\
\prodtime V & G_\mathrm{head},\,G_\mathrm{tail}
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: This helps, it's not exactly what I had in mind but I think I can get there.

Comment: Cheers, this looks really good.

Comment: @PaulBone: Please consider upvoting answers (and other questions) that are useful to you, and also using the check mark to select the one that helped you the most in getting to your solution.

Comment: Don't forget to say `\mathit{foreign}` and `G_\mathrm{head}` for better appearance of the formulas. You don't need `\,` after `\prodtime` if it's declared as an operator (as you did).

Comment: @egreg: I assume then one should also use `\mathit{time\_of\_call}`.

Comment: Yes, or `\textit` as well.

Comment: I've since modified this algorithm's typesetting.  I'm now using the stmaryrd font and style so that I can use double braces around the second argument of prodtime (as they're deconstructions of a single data term).  (Writing this here so other people can find the name of the stmaryrd package.)

Comment: @PaulBone: If that is an answer you should add an answer here with an example.

Answer (score 2):

The `cases` environment of [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) allows bracing on the left hand side:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\newcommand{\fib}{\mathrm{fib}}
\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
  \fib\,X = \begin{cases}
    1 & \text{if } X<2 \\
    \fib(X-1)+\fib(X-2) & \text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

The contents of `cases` is much like that of an `array`. In fact, if you want more control over element placement, the following produces an equivalent output:

```
\begin{gather*}
  \fib\,X = \left\{\begin{array}{@{}l@{\quad}l}
    1 & \text{if } X<2 \\[\jot]
    \fib(X-1)+\fib(X-2) & \text{otherwise}
  \end{array}\right.
\end{gather*}
```

Now you can even change the braces, or the alignment.

Comment: What I'd like, is for the if... and otherwise to appear on the left of the equation, the left of =.

Comment: I have used the cases environment when the expression naturally uses the if-else pattern.  Pattern matching is a different style of representing alternative code based on the structure of some data, which is the style I wanted.  Thanks though.